# My c++ programm keeps crashing ist my code bad?

Tags: c++, crash

Can somebody pls check if my code is bad? My command prompt crashes when I execute it.

I narrowed the problem down to this section:

```
    string result = "";
    result = pwpasst (username, password, "admin", "123");
    result = pwpasst (username, password, "root", "456");
    result = pwpasst (username, password, "peter", "789");
```

If I comment out 2 out of the 3 functions it seems to work. +
I don't know if my code is bad or of there is a problem with my command prompt.

The rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    string pwpasst (string username, string password, string un, string pw){
        if (username == un && password == pw)
        {
            return "You are logged in!";
        }
    };

int main()
{
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> username;

    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;


    string result = "";
    result = pwpasst (username, password, "admin", "123");
    result = pwpasst (username, password, "root", "456");
    result = pwpasst (username, password, "peter", "789");

    if (result != "You are logged in!"){
        cout << "Wrong password or username!";
    }   else { cout << result;}
}
```

Comment: Not all paths through `pwpasst ` return a value.

Comment: if `(username == un && password == pw)` evaluates to false, undefined-behaviour is invoked.

Comment: As a precaution you should compile you code always with options like `-Wall`, which would give you in this case a warning like `warning: control reaches end of non-void function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pwpasst() might return the string "You are ..."

But the else clause is missing and nothing is returned, a logic error.
Your function should always return the string it promised.

```
string pwpasst (string username, string password, string un, string pw)
{
   if (username == un && password == pw)
   {
      return "You are logged in!";
   }
   else 
   {
      // perhaps - but not a good choice.
      std::cerr << "unknown user name or password" << std::endl;
      return ""; // return null string
   }
};
```

Not a good choice because the previous would output 1, or 2 error messages each time.

---

In this code snippet, the three assignments will always be executed.

```
string result = "";
result = pwpasst (username, password, "admin", "123");
result = pwpasst (username, password, "root", "456");
result = pwpasst (username, password, "peter", "789");
```

You want to break out when you get a result, something like the following, (but this is not a good choice either):

```
string result = "";
do {
   result = pwpasst (username, password, "admin", "123");
            if(result.size()) break;
   result = pwpasst (username, password, "root", "456");  
            if(result.size()) break;
   result = pwpasst (username, password, "peter", "789");   
            if(result.size()) break;
}while(0);
```

Probably need to place the error message in this snippet, not in the function.

Some logic changes are required. Perhaps the function should return a bool (indicating valid name/pw or not), and the string 'result' might passed by reference for the function to fill in.

Comment: My typical options: -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement if `if (username == un && password == pw)` is false, and by your function definition, a `string` value needs to be returned by the function at the end. That invokes undefined behavior, which causes your program to terminate with a runtime error.

Comment: Note: there are other logic errors in your program. Since your question does not pertain to them, I have not included them here. If you have any further questions, you can ask me in the comments box.